# how to show splash screen in angularjs phonegap app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am developing app using angularjs and phonegap.
Using `"deviceready"` eventlistner I tried to show splash screen but its not working.

Here is the sample :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" onload="onLoad();">
    <script>
            function onDeviceReady() {
                navigator.splashscreen.show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
                }, 10000);
            }

            function onLoad() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
            }
        </script>
</body>
```

Can anyone help ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Splash screens are an anti-pattern: http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/ http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/07/trending-android-ui-anti-patterns.html http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhzAr9reu_4  https://medium.com/design-ux/f905a45b54dc Please do not waste the user's time with a splash screen.

Comment: thanks..:) but if it is a requirement, what can be the solution ?

Comment: Pass those links on to whoever made it a "requirement", and that person's boss, and up the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [Cordova splashscreen](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html) in cordova docs? It has all what you need :)